# jQuery events on keyboard issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a simple version of what I am looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/DLg92/5/

Now for a more complex version as here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/E7a9S/1/

The simple version works just fine. It has no issues and the event is completely corrent.

Now when you look at the more complex website, my event doesn't happen and I don't see why there is an issue.

I added the correct script to both websites and only the simple one is working.

I am trying to make it so that when a user click 'n' the text_input_box opens just like it would if you click the 'Add Note' button in the navigation menu.

I'm pretty new to jQuery and JavaScript so this is just a learning project I'm working on.

Thank you all for your time and help!

Comment: What do you mean by: "when a user click 'n'"?

Comment: @DanBarzilay if you look at the simple project, if you click n, the div appears and disappears.. when you look at the more complex post it website, if u click n, the div doesnt appear as if the event wasnt triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright i found the problam actually its not in your code, and this is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E7a9S/5/

The problam was that you included mootools in jsfiddle that made jquery not work properly.

the simple version worked just fine because if you notice there you actually did included the jquery and not the mootools.

***btw** the advanced one is just beautiful and is really cool.*

Good Luck!

Comment: Also make sure jquery is included before your other scripts that depend on it.

Comment: That didn't solve my problem. Take a look here if you don't mind. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3pX0FP4D -- this is the raw code from the page.. If you look at the page in live action here ( http://pastehtml.com/view/c8npfc37t.html 0

Comment: you should copy the exact html code from my updated fiddle, yours version includes the shortkeys plugin before including the jquery library itself.

Comment: whoops, i got it! your html was completely right! ahah thank you sooo much for your helpp!

Comment: Now it does i updated it the problam was that you need jquery version 1.7.2 and it was 1.8

Answer (score 1):

It won't fix your problem, but here's a few things to improve your js:

```
$(".postIt-" + id).css("width",wh);
$(".postIt-" + id).css("height",wh);
$(".postIt-" + id).css("transform","rotate("+rotatedegree+"deg)");
// ...
```

Don't repeat `$(".postIt-" + id)`, it's slower and useless:

```
$(".postIt-" + id).css("width",wh)
.css("height",wh)
.css("transform","rotate("+rotatedegree+"deg)")
// ...
```

Instead of this:

```
if (randomBg == 1){
    $(".postIt-" + id).addClass("bg_one");
}
if (randomBg == 2){
    $(".postIt-" + id).addClass("bg_two");
}
```

Do this:

```
var setRandomBg = function(postit_id, bg_id) {
    $(".postIt-" + postit_id).addClass("bg_" + bg_id); // you would need to rename your classes with numbers
}
// and call it

setRandomBg(id, randomBg);
```